# Optimized way for changing all the colors of my UIView's elements programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview

I have an UIView with different kind of elements inside (UIButton, UIImageView, UIImageView animations). At some moment, when the user select it, I want to switch all this view to grayscale.

At the moment I do one element after one so for exemple my element 1 of my UIView:

```
UIImage *newImg = [[myButton1 backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] convertToGrayscale];
[myButton1 setBackgroundImage:newImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It is working fine but I receive a Memory Warning (=1) when I do so...Maybe because I got more than 20 elements in my UIView to change (including an animation).

So I would like to know if there is a better way for changing all the elements colors of my UIView ? Like maybe blending a white square in Luminosity mode on the top of my UIView...would that be possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final result is probably not using to much memory, just the intermediate objects that are autoreleased (including autoreleased objects the API is using).

Consider creating an autoreleasePool inside you loop so the autoreleased objects are fully released every iteration.  The over head of an autoreleasePool is rather small.

Example:

```
for ( /*your loop */ ) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    /* Your code */

    [pool drain];
}
```